# How to load a Banner module inside an IFrame in Dot net nuke

Tags: iframe, dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-5, dotnetnuke-module

I'm new to dot net nuke and I'm searching for a way to load a banner module inside an iframe.

How to figure out this?

Comment: Normally DNN modules are not loaded in an iFrame but rather in a content area inside of the DotNetNuke skin - can you clarify what you are doing?

Comment: well my intention was to place a dnn banner module within the html module

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modules are not loaded into an iFrame or an HTML module. Normally you would have a module that has the specific function you want and then place that in a content section in the site. In the case of DNN there is a banner module. You can see some hints on using it in the video.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iRzrTgUH8Hk